# A secure enough way of identifying and activating a user in MySQL PHP with a URL

Tags: php, mysql

Is checking against my table with the `user's email` and dedicated `hash` enough to verify and activate an account if a match is found against those two values?

A user is asked to register themselves with user data and their email id. They are then sent a URL to their email which they are asked to click on to confirm and activate their account.

This is my current setup:

```
<?php //The user-account-creation processing page

    $email_id = taken from user input;
    $randomnessWhateverItsCalled = "lots-of-randomness-here";

    UPDATE advert SET advert_hash = SHA1(CONCAT($email_id, $randomnessWhateverItsCalled))

    //For simplicity's sake I omitted the PDO stuff
    INSERT INTO table_name (..., user_email, hash, account_activated, ...) VALUES (..., usersEmail, advert_hash, NO, ...) 


    /**
        Send an email with some php code with the URL that would look like this
        URL to click on attached to email body: 
     */
     $attachStringToEmailBody = "http://www.domainname.com/activate-user?email_id=" . $usersEmail . "&hash=" . $randomnessWhateverItsCalled;
enter code here

    //Send email from this process page with a little email php code  

    //Redirect user to a page informing the user to activate the account by visiting their email and clicking on the url
?>
```

Then in the `activate-user.php` page I have the following:

```
<?ph
    $user_email = $_GET['email_id'];
    $hash = $_GET['hash'];


   /**
        search database and return a row if there is a match containing both the $user_email and the $hash
        if(match){
            Update database and set the `account_activated` column to `YES`
        }
        else{
            //Tell if there was no match then activation failed

            //Let the user know that we do not recognise the link they used to try and activate their account.
        }
        */

?>
```

Comment: Please read about [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) to get an idea about security standards and perhaps even to use the ready-made library.

Comment: @MihaiStancu, Hi, could you please explain how your comment answers my question?

Comment: Pavan my answer is not an answer it's a comment which perfectly explains why it does not answer the question.

Comment: Comments are used for collateral (related) information (requests as well as offers). I'm just offering you some collateral reading material.

Answer (score 0):

It seems secure enough, as long as you made the "randomness" part hard to guess. You can put there the email, username, password, etc. and mix them up with another key - all encrypted - that's what I usually do.

But I would advise you to use 0/1 for active/inactive - why using strings, when you can do the same with smallint (1) - and save some space, thus making the database a bit lighter ?

Comment: while I agree that `boolean` or `tinyint(1)` are much more adequate to be used as active/inactive flags I do not fully agree with the reason.

Comment: It's always better to use expressive, easy to comprehend, "standard" structures because it helps with predictability of form and function. Meaning that a boolean field called `status` will be easy to comprehend  without further documentation.

Comment: Why not? It's less space on the database, faster to search/sort.. ?

Comment: Saving a couple of bytes (although a good thing) is nowhere near as necessary as it was a decade ago. I'm in no way condoning the (ab)use of space -- quite the contrary, if you can save some space that means your indexes/keys for that column will also be faster to read. But if you're saving 2 bytes from `varchar 'yes'` to `boolean true` the difference in indexes is insesizable (including size and speed), and the difference in actuall disk space is negligible compared to available space.

Comment: But the real differences are between int(10) vs. bigint(20) vs. uuid identifier columns, large (indexed) varchar columns, large (fulltext indexed) text columns. Because these severely affect size on disk, size of indexes, speed of searching, speed of intersections/joins etc..

Comment: Interesting discussion. @mariobgr, I am actually not saving that boolean as a string, instead it's being saved as a `tinyint(1)`. However, after Mihai's argument, I may consider saving entries as `boolean true` instead as that would make data more readable and typcasting between a local app and database unecessary since data would be arriving in the right data format. Then again, typecasting an `int` to a `boolean` really isn't intensive locally, so I guess the only advantage would be easier readability then.

Comment: @pavan mysql silently converts any `boolean` to `tinyint(1)`, any `TRUE` to `1` and any `FALSE` to `0`. This is because MySQL does not (actually) support boolean columns and because the ANSI-SQL standards do not force implementations to support `boolean`. I prefer using `BOOLEAN` as well as `TRUE`/`FALSE` for the expressive effect.

Comment: @MihaiStancu hah, fantastic then. I guess the typecasting in my app would still need to be done locally as its done with `Tinyint` but to have the added advantage of readability is definitely worth it then.

Comment: @mariobgr are you saying to add as many things as I can to form the hash?

Comment: The hash is supposed to be hard to guess, right? If so, yes, the more things are concatenated and encrypted together, the harder it is to guess...